# How does importing modules work in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I am currently working on a project using python. I have the following tree structure for the directories (I cut all the venv subfolders).

[image: Tree structure cutting out the venv]

Inside the models folder there is a file called builder that contains the class `Builder`. This class needs the c3d and i3d classes inside, respectively, the backbones and heads folder.
For testing, I tried to add to the builder file a call to the `Builder` constructor and it seems to work just fine, but when I try to construct a `Builder` in the main it gives me the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backbones'`

To provide you an example of how the code should work, inside the c3d and i3d files I have some imports from pytorch, in builder I have `from backbones import c3d` and `from heads import i3d`, while in main I have `from models.builder import Builder`.

I found some old questions saying that creating a **init**.py file should be enough to solve this problem since python looks for these files while importing modules, but I didn't get it fully, plus as you can see in the image I tried to apply this solution but still didn't work. Can someone please help me understand what did I do wrong and how should I make sure I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) while working inside packages.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using `main.py` as an entry point (i.e. the directory where `main.py` is in as the top), using an absolute import, `from backbones import c3d` will not find `backbones`. You would have to say `from models.backbones import c3d` to locate it, since absolute import finds packages by referencing `sys.path`, and unless you manually mess with it, it will only contain the top directory (along with the standard library locations).

You can also use a [relative import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) instead: `from .backbones import c3d`.